# Escher complex transform

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to get Escher's warped grid from this paper (figure 4)

From the paper I got the following formula (see page 450 marked as 'easy formula'):

$f(z) = e^{(\frac{0 + 2\pi i}{\ln(256) + 2\pi i})\ln(z)}$

When I apply this formula to an image of a grid I don't get the result I expected, see:

[Warped grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlNdn.png)

Which is beautiful and looks sort of correct, but misses a gap to the right. I can fill the gap by using the modulo operator when looking up pixels (uncomment line underneath # tile(?)). I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. I have the feeling the centering operation may be wrong. The paper does specify that the center of the image should be the origin. What follows is my attempt.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# supply image of grid here
im = cv2.imread('in.png')

height = im.shape[0]
width = im.shape[1]

new_im = np.zeros((height, width, 3))

def mod(x, y):
    return x - y*np.floor(x/y)

for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        z = np.array([i,j])
        # Center around origin and scale
        z = (z - np.array([height, width])/2.)/width

        # Convert to complex number
        z = z[0] + 1j*z[1]

        z = np.log(z)
        denom = (0.0 + 1j*2*np.pi)/(np.log(256.) + 1j*2*np.pi)
        z = z/denom
        z = np.exp(z)

        z = np.array([z.real, z.imag])

        try:
            # rescale
            z = z*width
            z += np.array([height, width])/2.
            # tile (?)
            #z = np.array([mod(z[0], width), mod(z[1], height)])
            # Retrieve pixel from original image
            new_im[i][j][0] = im[int(z[0])][int(z[1])][0]
            new_im[i][j][1] = im[int(z[0])][int(z[1])][1]
            new_im[i][j][2] = im[int(z[0])][int(z[1])][2]

        except:
            pass

cv2.imwrite("out.png", new_im)
```

I suspect that something that should be periodic is being clamped or only mapped once. Like the complex logarithm has multiple solutions. I don't know whether that matters. I'm a maths enthusiast yet amateur and I might (probably) be something completely wrong.

Edit: this is what it should look like:
http://davidbau.com/conformal/#exp(((2*3.1415926*i%20%2B%20log(256))%2F(0%2B2*3.1415926*i))*log(z))